# How can I change li styles to use a character?

Tags: css

I'm writing a tutorial with a lot of content that looks like this:

> $ type something at a Bash prompt
>   > type something at an IRB prompt

In other tutorials, I almost always see the `$` and `>` prompts written inline, but it seems more appropriate to style my `li`s with CSS.

I've found two approaches to doing this:

```
ul li:before {
  content: "\003E \0020";
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

and:

```
ul {
  list-style-image: url(irb.gif);
}
```

Neither feels good to me. The first doesn't actually change the `li` style: it just hides it and adds a character beforehand. The second uses an image when a character should do the trick.

Is there another, better way? If not, which of these two is preferable?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to add a character, not an image, what's the problem with the first option? The character is non-selectable and purely presentational, so in what way is it not '[changing] the style'?

Comment: @DavidThomas, I've updated my question to correct part of the CSS that was missing. Basically, the first way is hiding the list style and adding something new. It might be the only way to do this, but it feels a bit yucky to me.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [less](http://lesscss.org/) and do:

```
    li { you:style;
         another:style;


      &:before {  content: "\003E \0020"; }

  }
```

Comment: you need less if you want to style the LI and add before in the same brackets for better readability

Comment: That actually looks *less* readable, to me, than plain CSS. Which can do exactly the same thing.

Comment: this is a subjective view. for me this is the preferable solution. in one place you have all styles for the <li>.

Comment: @John, what answer are you referring to?